# AWS Elastic Load Balancer connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I set up a load balancer in a Availability Zone and added some EC2 instances in the same zone. The health check works fine. Now I tried to access the load balancer using its host name from outside. Even though I can access individual hosts behind the load balancer without any issue, I got a connection time-out error if I tried to connect to the load balancer:

```
$ wget -O test "http://xxxx.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/" 
--2014-04-01 21:26:59--  http://xxxx.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/
Resolving xxxx.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com... 11.111.111.11
Connecting to xxxx.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com|11.111.111.11|:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
```

Listener configuration is like this (I don't know how to format this better):

```
Load Balancer Protocol | Load Balancer Port | Instance Protocol | Instance Port | Cipher | SSL Certificate
HTTP                     8080                 HTTP                8080            N/A      N/A
```

Any insight/comment would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a listener set up on port 8080 for the load balancer? What does the Listeners tab say on the EC2 ELB control panel for that load balancer?

Comment: @jlahd, I edited my posting to add my listener configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that it was because I set it up as VPC Load Balancer. In that case I have to access it through a private IP address :)